# In merge sort algorithm, will freeing the left and right sub arrays after the arrays have been merged make any difference in the space complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, space-complexity

In one of the tutorial videos for merge sort, it was mentioned that once the right and left sub arrays have to merged to the parent array, in order to reduce the space complexity we need to free the memory allocated for the left and right sub arrays. But whenever we come out of the function call, the local variable will be destroyed. Do correct me if I am wrong. So will the action of freeing the memory make any difference?

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void mergeArr(int *rarr, int *larr, int *arr, int rsize, int lsize) {
    int i = 0, r = 0, l = 0;

    while (r < rsize && l < lsize) {
        if (rarr[r] < larr[l]) {
            arr[i++] = rarr[r++];
        } else {
            arr[i++] = larr[l++];
        }
    }
    while (r < rsize) {
        arr[i++] = rarr[r++];
    }
    while (l < lsize) {
        arr[i++] = larr[l++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int length) {
    if (length > 1) {
        int l1 = length / 2;
        int l2 = length - l1;
        int rarr[l1], larr[l2];

        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
            rarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = l1; i < length; i++) {
            larr[i - l1] = arr[i];
        }

        mergeSort(rarr, l1);
        mergeSort(larr, l2);
        mergeArr(rarr, larr, arr, l1, l2);
        // will free(rarr); free(larr); make any difference in space complexity
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = { 1, 10, 2, 7, 5 };
    mergeSort(arr, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: You might want to tag this as C++ for better feedback on your specific implementation. In a language without manual memory management your idea makes sense - the garbage collector _should_ remove the left and right sub-arrays when they are no longer referenced.

Comment: As written, the code will run out of stack space for a large array (and it won't compile on Visual Studio, which doesn't allow variable length arrays). Rather than allocating 2 arrays for each level of recursion, it would be better to do a one time allocation of a working array up front in an entry function, then pass the address of the working array into the actual merge sort functions. When complete, the working array would be freed (deleted).

Comment: There's no variable-length arrays in C++, and if there was they would be freed automatically when the block exits. Calling `free` on them would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation, the left and right arrays are defined with automatic storage, so deallocation is automatic when the function returns but it poses 2 problems:

- a sufficiently large array will invoke undefined behavior because allocating too much space with automatic storage will cause a **stack overflow**.
- variable sized arrays are not standard C++. You are relying on a compiler specific extension.

The maximum stack space used by your function is proportional to `N`, so the space complexity is **O(N)** as expected. You could allocate these arrays with `new`, and of course you would then have to deallocate them with **delete** otherwise you would have memory leaks and the amount of memory lost would be proportional to **N*log2(N)**.

An alternative approach would use a temporary array, allocated at the initial call and passed to the recursive function.

Note also that the names for the left and right arrays are very confusing. `rarr` is actually to the left of `larr`!

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mergeArr(int *larr, int *rarr, int *arr, int lsize, int rsize) {
    int i = 0, r = 0, l = 0;

    while (l < lsize && r < rsize) {
        if (larr[l] <= rarr[r]) {
            arr[i++] = larr[l++];
        } else {
            arr[i++] = rarr[r++];
        }
    }
    while (l < lsize) {
        arr[i++] = larr[l++];
    }
    while (r < rsize) {
        arr[i++] = rarr[r++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int length) {
    if (length > 1) {
        int l1 = length / 2;
        int l2 = length - l1;
        int *larr = new int[l1];
        int *rarr = new int[l2];

        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
            larr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = l1; i < length; i++) {
            rarr[i - l1] = arr[i];
        }

        mergeSort(larr, l1);
        mergeSort(rarr, l2);
        mergeArr(larr, rarr, arr, l1, l2);
        delete[] larr;
        delete[] rarr;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 10, 2, 7, 5 };
    int length = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    mergeSort(arr, length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have multiple things to say about this. More from a C++ pov:

1. `int rarr[l1],larr[l2];` - this is illegal c++. This is just an extension provided by g++ and is not valid across other compilers. You should either do `int* rarr = new int[l1];` or even better use an `std::vector`: `std::vector<int> rarr(l1)`.
2. If you are doing the former (dynamic allocation using `new` i.e `int* rarr = new int[l1]`), you have to manage the memory on your own. So when you're done using it you have to delete it: `delete[] rarr`. Mind it, `malloc` and `free` are not c++, they are c. `new` and `delete` are c++ way of allocating/deallocating memory.
3. If you use a vector, c++ will handle the deletion/deallocation of memory so you need not worry.

Now coming back to your original question: whether or not an idea like this would improve your space complexity: the answer is **NO**. It won't.

Why? Think about the max temporary storage you're using. Check the first case of your recursion. Isn't the space that you're using `O(N)`? because larr and rarr will both be of size `N/2`. Moreover, the space complexity is `O(N)` assuming the temporary storage is being freed. If somehow the space is not freed, the space complexity will increase to `O(N)+2*(N/2)+4*O(N/4)....` which is `O(Nlog2N)` because each step of recursion is allocating some space which it is not freeeing.

Comment: If the space complexity changes from **O(N)** to **O(N.log2(N))**, does this not mean that freeing the space **does** make a difference?

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes not freeing the space allocated using `new` or `malloc` is a memory leak. It should not be considered as making a difference, but more as that, if the program is not freeing up dynamically allocated space, then the program is malformed.

Comment: I respectfully disagree: not freeing memory is not necessarily an error, it can be a design decision for programs that are known to require a limited amount of memory, whether they run for a short time or not. It may be seen as a sloppy design decision, but in case of complicated graph-like structures with multiple cross references, the compromise between controlled memory leaks and complex memory handling may lead to such decisions. If the memory is not freed by choice, the space complexity **does** increase. Of course, in this particular case there is no reason not to free the blocks.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Ok. I see your point. But if it's about "complex memory handling" one can just use stl containers which implement raii or if it's about cross references, perhaps smart pointers will do the trick. If it's about performance, one can use a memory pool (or if applicable placement new). But perhaps you have some other usecase in mind which I'm unable to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Freeing temporary arrays does not influence on space complexity because we must consider maximum memory consumption - it is about size of initial array.

From the performance point of view, it seems reasonable to allocate temporary storage once in the beginning of sorting, reuse it at every stage, and free it after all the work is done.